# Why is NOMA needed in 5G?

Tags: frequency-spectrum, lte, noma

Although there is wide band spectrum in 5G from 6GHz to 300 GHz, why is NOMA needed in 5G to enhance spectrum efficiency. We can communicate in different frequencies since we have very large band. Are resources limited in 5G?

Comment: Welcome. NOMA is a very broad subject, even within 5G NR. Please specify the use case.

Comment: "Are resources limited?" Of course there are limited resources. 6 to 300 GHz doesn't belong to 5G, only a small portion of it does, and only a small portion of it is useful. You'll always want to be most efficient with the resources you've got, no matter how much you get, as long as you can foresee a chance of reducing power usage or increasing profit through more users.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got this. @MarcusMüller